# A non-constant Measure that vanishes for finite subsets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I found a note while rehearsing saying:

There isnt a non-constant Measure $\mu :  \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, so that all finite subsets of $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ vanish.

Im pretty unsure on that so I would appreciate any help here

Comment: I guess $\mathcal{P}(X)$ should be $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Sorry it should be $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ (edited it).So that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ should be right.

Comment: I guess then that the measure should vanish on all finite subsets $Y\subseteq X$.

Comment: In $ZF$ without choice, it is consistent to assume every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable.  So, any proof of this statement is going to need to use the axiom of choice at some point - and in a very strong way, since in fact $ZF$ + dependent choice + every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, is also consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a measure could be extended to all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, so assume it is defined for every set of reals. There must be some closed interval of length $1$ that has measure $1$. Divide it into two closed intervals of length $1/2$. One of them must have measure 1. Continuing this way, you get a nested sequence of compact intervals with diameter going to zero. So the intersection of all these intervals must contain a single point. But the measure would then assign measure 1 to the singleton set containing this point, in contradiction to the assumption that the measure vanishes on finite sets.

Comment: Wow this helped me alot. Thank you sir